# FatalExecutionEngineError while calling dll method

Tags: c#, .net

In my program on this line:

```
int value = MTEConnect(auth_string, err);
```

I receive such exeption:

```
FatalExecutionEngineError 
The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the
error was at 0x68c8a681, on thread 0x2334. The error code is
0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe
or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this
bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke,
which may corrupt the stack.
```

MTEConnect is imported such a way:

```
    [DllImport("mtesrl.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern int MTEConnect(String pars, StringBuilder err);
```

What's the problem and how to fix it?

**upd:** I can reproduce the same problem on another machine, but I got a little more desriptive message:

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'C:\blahblah\MBClient\bin\Debug\MBClient.vshost.exe
```

Library itself is functional, because it can be used from another applications, I just can't use it from c#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved my problem!
Code doesn't work this way:

```
StringBuilder err = new StringBuilder();
int value = MTEConnect(auth_string, err);
```

But it do work this way:

```
StringBuilder err = new StringBuilder(100);
int value = MTEConnect(auth_string, err);
```

It seems buffer was too short.

Comment: me too :) spent a week solving thiz puzzle :)

Comment: +1 Saved me a day when I used _StringBuilder_ for _GetDefaultPrinter_ of Win32 Spooler DLL (winspool.drv)

Answer (score 1):

A `FatalExecutionEnigneError` is often the result of corruption within the core CLR native code that leads to a fatal native exception.  When it occurs at the site of a `PInvoke` call it's a big indicator the `PInvoke` signature is incorrect.

Could you provide the native signature so we can help diagnose this problem?

Comment: I don't know what is native signature, where can I get it? probably I can just share dll that i'm using, if it would help?

Comment: if it's important then I have 2 versions of the same dll. they supposed to be "compatible", i.e. it should be possible to substitute one to another. However when my code works with one dll, it doesn't work with another (without any changes to the code)

Comment: I've placed dll that doesn't work here http://zalil.ru/31055951 (also I can send you by e-mail if you prefer :)

Comment: @javapowered do you have the header file where the function MTEConnect is defined?

Comment: I don't have .h file of this certain library now, but i'm pretty sure that function must be declared like that "int32 WINAPI MTEConnect(char *Params, char *ErrorMsg);". I will ask developer of the library for *.h file tomorrow... Probably it's possible to extract information you request from *dll file somehow?...

Comment: @javapowered unfortunately DLLs from C code lack the required metadata to generate a PInvoke signature. You really need the .h file and a bit of semantic knowledge about the API to get the PInvoke signature.

Comment: Sorry I still can't find .h file. But i posted the signature in the comment above and I absolutely sure about it. Taking into account that function takes two LPSTR parameters and returns int what could be a problem theoreticaly in my C# code? Can we guess what could be changed? Honestly I think the signature is OK, because my code works with another version of the library. Also DLL is functional. Probably problem in some other places? What else could cause FEEE? May I submit a bug to Microsoft? May it be a bug in .NET? I almost sure that my signature is OK

Comment: @javapowered it's possible this PInvoke is OK and another one earlier is the culprit. Errors like these are often very hard to track down due to it usually being memory corruption in the CLR.  I would start by removing my PInovke calls one at a time until the error went away ot figure out the most likely one

Comment: I got exception when invoking MTEConnect(auth_string, err); if i will remove MTEConnect call, i will not get exception... but I need to call MTEConnect.... i.e. I don't understand what you suggest to remove...

Comment: Finally I found how to solve my issue, see my answer :) Thank you for trying to help!