# Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError'

Tags: debugging

I'm getting below error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users\App\App.exe'.
>   Additional Information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0xf5b029e1, on thread 0x72bc. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

I get the above error when i execute this statement while debugging.

```
 LoggerHandler.Info("Executed " & iterations.ToString & " iterations on " & max_processors & " cores in " & Format((Now() - time).TotalSeconds, "0.0") & " seconds.")
```

Comment: When you use a StringBuilder in DllImport
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6070008/4841381

Answer (score 11):

Changing to use "Managed Compatibility Mode" is what fixed the error for me in Visual Studio 2015:

> Tools menu >Options > Debugging > General > "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"

[image]

This [Microsoft blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/) describes what this setting does in a bit more detail.

Comment: i'm seeing similar errors, and this option not work, can you help take a look here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213605/managed-debugging-assistant-fatalexecutionengineerror-occurred

Comment: I have same errors, when I enable "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" it shows me below error when I run the program again:

"The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x722f5a90, on thread 0xeb8. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack."

NOTE: I'm using 
[DllImport("swedll32.dll", EntryPoint = "_swe_julday@24")]. Not sure but swedll32.dll is unmanaged c/c++ dll.

Comment: nowadays, with VS 2019, this error occurs when the condition on `catch(ex) when (condition)` evaluates to a `NullReferenceException`. When this happens, your app crashes; visual studio throws fatal execution engine error

Answer (score 8):

I recently hit this error and spent about 10hrs diagnosing the issue only to find the latest version of **Cylance** was interfering.

Essentially, **Cylance memory protection** was blocking local debug of web based projects (ASP and WCF were in our scope). Hope this saves someone else some time troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the hidden .vs folder in the solution directory.

Comment: This solution saved me several hours.

Comment: I faced the same problem again, and searching the internet pointed out the solution again, where I see my own comment :)

Comment: Just deleting the directory was not enough for me, I had to do a clean and full rebuild of the solution. I guess the .PDB (obj directory) were "corrupted".

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue:

> Tools -> options -> [IntelliTrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMlA8.png) -> General

and check "Events Only" option

Comment: where this option is coming in vs2017?