# Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' occurred

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

i got the following error while **DEBUG** a test, however the same test can **RUN** successfully.
[image]

when I turn on the option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" under Tools->Option->Debugging->General, the error box changed to following:

[image]

Is there any clue what's going on?
I'm using the visual studio 2015.

Comment: Are You using unmanaged code which has corrupted memory?

Comment: @Alois, i'm using unmanaged code from other teams. i don't know whether it has corrupted memory there or not. but the strange thing is it can run successfully, only failed to debug.

Comment: During debugging you are using the debug heap which does more things to prevent hidden memory corruptions.You should talk to the team to help you debugging that issue.

Comment: @Dingxin Xu, how did you debug your app, from the test explorer window or general debugging? Is it related to the Nunit like this case? https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/979681/visual-studio-throws-fatalexecutionengineerror-when-debugging-a-specflow-unit-test-and-switching-back-from-c-to-the-feature-file

Comment: im getting the same issue, have you found the solution for this?

Comment: Same issue, same question as @Bilal, one of you found a solution?
For me my application was just sitting in the background while I was doing other stuff, on my first call again I got this error.