# How to find source code when I only know the address of error

Tags: .net, vb.net, fatal-error

When I get the following error, how do I find which .vb file and code line it is?

[image]

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451431/managed-debugging-assistant-fatalexecutionengineerror). There's also a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042920/fatalexecutionengineerror-after-restarting-debug-session) that anti-malware software can cause this.

Comment: No.  I tried that.  I need to look at the source code that causes the error, but I only know the "address of the error" and not the source code file or the line number.

Comment: You don't use the information in the screenshot.  You click the link for more details.  If you're in Visual Studio, you use the "Automatic variables" watch window to see all the exception properties and stack trace.  If you're not, you can also open Task Manager, find the process on the "Details" tab, right-click, and create a dump file that you can load in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Doug Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823440/troubleshooting-net-fatal-execution-engine-error)

Comment: The exception is thrown on your production system?