# FatalExecutionEngineError occurring with DateTime objects

Tags: c#, exception

I have this line of code which sometimes gets a `FatalExecutionEngineError` exception:

`Double? TimeTakenToStopProbe = Math.Round(((TimeSpan)(ProbeEndDateTime - CancelationRequestDateTime)).TotalSeconds, 3);`

where `ProbeEndDateTime` and `CancelationRequestDateTime` are not null `DateTime` objects with valid dates and times in them.

The full exception explanation given to me by Visual Studio is the following:

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' 
  Message=Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' : 'The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x7664bee8, on thread 0x1eac0. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.'
```

Can someone explain to me what is causing this exception ?

Comment: Did you search online for this issue? What did you try? Please read this thread and revert if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451431/managed-debugging-assistant-fatalexecutionengineerror

Comment: Is this core or framework, what visual studio are you running, are you in administrator mode, does this happen in release config. There is a lot of missing information here. however there is a lot of similar issues online, some are classed as bugs